# In Little Inferno, which items should I never burn?

Tags: little-inferno

In Little Inferno, the player burns objects. Occasionally, the player receives objects he would not be able to buy. These objects take some space in the inventory, which makes the game more tedious to complete. In order to get the hardest to achieve ending, which of these items should I never burn? All of them? Just one of them? For instance, the following object?

> Hug Coupon

Comment: This was tested on another forum - keeping every item she gives you and burning them together does nothing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a list of the "unique" items:

1. Photo of Someone
2. Paper Heart
3. Thermometer
4. Delete Key
5. Free Hug Coupon
6. Novelty Mouse Pad

And this is the list of the items that are confirmed to change the ending somehow:

> 1. Free Hug Coupon

And these are confirmed NOT to affect the ending:

> 1. Novelty Mouse Pad

Whether or not the others do as well has yet to be tested as far as I know, and whether or not they can be used in some kind of secret combo with each other has not been documented either.

Comment: Can you or anyone else followup on this answer? I'm also interested to know.

Comment: After beating it twice I haven't done any further research. Suggested edits are welcome though.