# When does Little Inferno save?

Tags: little-inferno

I accidentally burned a [one-of-a
-kind item](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/93729/181240) while playing Little Inferno. I closed the game within seconds hoping the game hadn't saved, only to find my item gone once I started the game up again.

When does Little Inferno save? Is it possible to quit without saving?